# Import and use data in QtableViewb in Qt5designer

Tags: python

My Window(created by Qt5 designer) has two Tabs ('movies' and 'Kart')

My Table(T1)(1st Tab) has 6 rows {{Movies, Genre, Ratings, Rent(Rs), Buy(Rs).}}

Now,
I have made a table(T1) with Qt5designer(in 1st Tab) and have enabled selection.

I want:

1. A way to take data(ie Movie name and price) from this table(T1) and create a Bill/ invoice in 2nd Tab BASED ON USER SELECTION..

Note: these tabs are in same window GUI

I can use python 3.6 and mysql 8.0 only.

Comment: Will you please read this [link](https://likegeeks.com/pyqt5-tutorial/) this might help you.

Comment: Plz respond this is for a school project

Comment: Didn't helped but thank you sir

Comment: Ohh! I am sorry John.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider reading [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions, and consider that this is not a place where people normally asks others to "get things done for them". If you've got some code already, then explain what is your issue or what you don't understand, providing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of that code. If you're just asking "how can I do that" instead, sorry but you're out of luck, and if that's a school assignment then it's one more reason for that.